# How to solve problem in Python 3: No module named 'unix'

Tags: drivers, python3

I installed pymouse using pip3. In python interpreter I tryed to do import of pymouse: `import pymouse` and got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymouse/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from unix import PyMouse, PyMouseEvent
ImportError: No module named 'unix'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you install pymouse ?

On github it says that

> PyMouse has been merged into PyUserInput at
>   https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput

Maybe you should try to install this module instead.

"unix.py" seems to be a [file|module](https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse/blob/master/pymouse/unix.py) from (outdated) pymouse package. Try to [download pymouse](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) from git as zip and to run it locally, see if it works (just unzip the folder, run python3 shell from the unzipped folder and import).